# Extract drawn paths from PDF files using PHP & Linux

Tags: php, linux, pdf, plugins

I'm looking for a solution / API (i.e. like PDFLib) that can extract (and remove) a drawn path from a graphic PDF.  For example a path that outlines a picture or logo that was drawn in Illustrator or Indesign (not JPG clipping path), that is set to a specific spot color (ie "CutContour").  I need to get the data that makes up that path to extract for use in a cutting system.

While PDFLib can extract text, it cannot extract graphic elements. I'm even open to solutions outside of PHP!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find any php pdf parsers, but...

If you aren't opposed to using an alternate language, I found a ruby gem that will parse a pdf file. From the docs it looks like you're able to grab a hash of the objects of a file.

http://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-reader

If you're looking for a pure programmatic solution that might work, but seems like it would be difficult.

Otherwise, I know that you can open up pdf files in Adobe Illustrator and extract graphics that way. You might even be able to write some javascripts that will automate the process. This solution obviously won't work on linux though.